# fancybox works on one server but not another

Tags: fancybox, lightbox

I have uploaded my website to two different servers hosted by two different companies.

This version is hosted by Newtek Technology Services:

http://urbanresearchtheater.com/esr2012/r_paintings.htm

This version is hosted by Midphase:

http://www.espatzrabinowitz.com/newsite2012/r_paintings.htm

The first site works great, but on the second, fancybox does nothing! The coding and everything is exactly the same, so I think there must be a problem with something on the Midphase host. Maybe something is not turned on or installed properly. I don't know. Has anyone encountered this and can suggest how I might fix the problem on the second site?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

In the second link (your new host at Midphase), all your fancybox files return a `404` error, which it means that the files are not in the place you said, for instance :

http://www.espatzrabinowitz.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.0

....doesn't exists so either or you modified the `path` or you just simply forgot to upload the fancybox files in the `/fancybox/source/` directory

**UPDATE**: found them!!!

http://www.espatzrabinowitz.com/newsite2012/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.0

... so your right directory/path (from root) is `/newsite2012/fancybox/source/`